# Cannot gem install ruby-augeas on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rubygems, puppet, augeas

I am trying to install augeas on Ubuntu.

```
    sudo gem install ruby-augeas
```

This gives me the error:

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing ruby-augeas:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
            --with-opt-dir
            --without-opt-dir
            --with-opt-include
            --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
            --with-opt-lib
            --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
            --with-make-prog
            --without-make-prog
            --srcdir=.
            --curdir
            --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
            --with-augeas-config
            --without-augeas-config
            --with-pkg-config
            --without-pkg-config
    extconf.rb:27:in `<main>': augeas-devel not installed (RuntimeError)
```

I had

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev ruby1.9.1-dev augeas-tools libaugeas-dev
```

Btw, where is the `mkmf.log` file?

How should I install augeas? I need to install it using gem as this will be used for Puppet's version of Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need at least build-essential package to compile native extensions. Also make sure you have all the ruby base libraries precompiled (or in the rvm).

Try to install rvm itself, it will give you a list of required packages just after installation.